# utf-8 characters in latex math mode

Tags: math-mode, unicode, font-encodings

I'm using utf-8 characters like "ğ" or "ı" in math-mode in LaTex, but it does not render the characters as it should. Outside of math-mode I do not have this problem.

My preamble with respect to font and input encoding is:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

Any pointers on how to fix this problem for math-mode?

Comment: What font(s) are you using?  Could you post a compilable example which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/5764) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: Should the first have the same output as `$\hat{g}$`?

Comment: Normally no math font provides such characters. Supported characters are normal math symbols.

Answer (score 5):

First of all be warned, that it is not recommended to use such special chars in your math source code, as they are very hard to distinguish from each other. For example look at `ğ` (`\breve{g}`) and `ǧ` (`\check{g}`) or `ı` (dottless i U+0131) and `ι` (`\iota`).

If you still need it, the way to go these days is to use either `xetex` or `luatex` for compilation and the `unicode-math` package. In this example, my math font does not contain a native character `ğ`, so I also have to declare it with `\newunicodechar`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec,unicode-math}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{STIXGeneral}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}

\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{ğ}{\ifmmode\breve{g}\else ğ\fi}

\begin{document}
    Text-mode: ğ,ı and math-mode: $ğ,ı$.
\end{document}
```