# Is there any documentation of \Umathcode, \Umathcodenum, etc.?

Tags: documentation, unicode-math

Trying to use the package `unicode-math` I have been looking for some documentation of `\Umathcode`, `\Umathcodenum`, etc. The usually place, the package documentation (http://ctan.org/pkg/unicode-math), does not contain such. Unfortunately, I am not (yet) able to read LaTeX3 source code.

For example, by trial and error it seems that `` \Umathcode`C="x"yy"zzzz `` is the right syntax of `\Umathcode`. Of course, that is different from `` \mathcode`C="xyzz `` (at least in the number of bits...).

So how is the syntax of `\Umathcode`, `\Umathcodenum`, `\Umathchar`, `\Umathchardef`, ...?

Comment: xetex-reference.pdf says on p. 14: *\Umathchar ⟨math type⟩ ⟨fam.⟩ ⟨glyph slot⟩ typesets the math character in the ⟨glyph slot⟩ in the family specified.* Still, I don't see where the parts (math type, fam, glyph slot) are described. Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is some documentation in `xetexref`, although you need to be quite familiar with the TeX primitives they replace: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/xetexref

The `xetexref` document has a couple of known omissions that I haven't had the chance to fix up, but I think all the maths primitives are (now) in there.

You can also look in the LuaTeX reference documentation, which has analogous primitives with `U` prefix instead of `XeTeX`.

Comment: Thx! Yes, at the moment the `xetexref` documentation is missing some important information, e.g. what is "bit-packed" - `"1"4"2460` is not packed to `"1042460` but `"04202460` - maybe "fields-swapped-bit-packed" ;-). However, the LuaTeX reference contains all the necessary information! (At least a link/reference to the LuaTeX reference in the documentation of `xetexref` and `unicode-math` would be helpful.)

Comment: Yes. xetex-reference.pdf says on p. 14: *\Umathchar ⟨math type⟩ ⟨fam.⟩ ⟨glyph slot⟩ typesets the math character in the ⟨glyph slot⟩ in the family specified.* Still, I don't see where the parts (math type, fam, glyph slot) are described in greater detail (than the short para on p. 14 starting §2.3). Any help?