# How to use danish letters in equation/align?

Tags: equations, align, babel, characters, input-encodings

How to use æ, ø, å in LaTeX align?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
æ,ø,å
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

KR

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you really want to use `æ`, `ø`, and `å` as variables in math mode? If you want to write text in math mode use `\text{æ,ø,å}`. See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/98052/35864 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65599/35864

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! As math variables/inside function names or as text?

Comment: @moewe thank you very much. Could you transform it into an answer, so we can close the question? :-) and well, I don't like to use danish symbols in mathspace eather, but my instructor wants it so.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to write text in math mode use `\text{æ,ø,å}`.

See also [Umlauts in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/98052) and
[utf-8 characters in latex math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65599)