# Newly-Defined Scaled Bullet Point Not Being Scaled When Invoking New Definition

Tags: pdftex, fontsize, scaling, amssymb, definition

Consider the code

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{scalefnt}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand{\m}{\textcolor{blue}{{\scalefont{1.00}{\maltese}}}}
\newcommand{\M}{\textcolor{blue}{{\scalefont{3.00}{\maltese}}}}
\newcommand{\x}{\textcolor{red}{{\scalefont{1.00}{\bullet}}}}
\newcommand{\X}{\textcolor{red}{{\scalefont{3.00}{\bullet}}}}

\begin{document}
\noindent $\m$ \\[20pt]
$\M$ \\[40pt]
$\x$ \\[20pt]
$\X$
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

As you can see, the colorized and enlarged `\maltese` symbol as defined as `\M` seems to have been scaled properly, whereas, the colorized and enlarged `\bullet` symbol defined as `\X` is not being scaled at all. Am I doing something wrong?

QUESTION: What is preventing the newly defined colorized bullet point from being scaled properly; and how may I correct this?

Thank you.

Comment: I've no idea why `\bullet` is not enlarged. However, note that `\scalebox` does work, even if I guess it's not a super clean solution: `\newcommand{\X}{\scalebox{3.00}{\textcolor{red}{$\bullet$}}}`

Comment: Note also that you can use directly the utf-8 char • and it will scale well, but it won't work in math-mode directly since the math font does not have a symbol for it. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65599/utf-8-characters-in-latex-math-mode for a solution.

Comment: This isn't related to colour at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't change font size in math mode. The scalefont package unfortunately seems to avoid making the warning that the standard `\large` would make, but it still can't work that way. Switch size in text mode.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{scalefnt}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand{\m}{\textcolor{blue}{{\scalefont{1.00}{$\maltese$}}}}
\newcommand{\M}{\textcolor{blue}{{\scalefont{3.00}{$\maltese$}}}}
\newcommand{\x}{\textcolor{red}{{\scalefont{1.00}{$\bullet$}}}}
\newcommand{\X}{\textcolor{red}{{\scalefont{3.00}{$\bullet$}}}}

\begin{document}

\noindent \m \\[20pt]
\M \\[40pt]
\x \\[20pt]
\X
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for posting this answer. It works fine on my end. But I'm confused about what you said about "You can't change font size in math mode." I defined the new maltese cross in exactly the same manner as the new bullet. However, the new maltese cross was scaled properly in the output, whereas the new bullet was not. In fact, the maltese scaling was correctly produced whether I used `$\M$` or `\M`. Perhaps you would clarify this for me. Thank you.

Comment: `\maltese`  is defined using `\mathhexbox` so it is `\mbox{$ some math stuff $}` so the text font size change accidentally happens to affect the hidden nested math list. @mlchristians

Comment: Question: Should all commands that are essentially just wrappers around `\fontsize{size}{baselineskip}\selectfont` give a warning/error when used in math mode?

Comment: @User23456234 well if they don't give a higher level warning, then you will get a lower level one from `\selectfont` so depends how you value being friendly to users or being efficient on coding and run time by omitting the higher level tests